# Pytest: assert a list contains n instances of a class / object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

```py
@dataclass
class Component:
    name: str

class Assembly:
    def __init__():
        names = ["Able", "Baker", "Charlie"]
        self.components = [Component(name) for name in names]

def test_assembly():
    """Assembly should be initialised with three Components"""
    assembly = Assembly()
    assert assembly.components == [Component] * 3 # doesn't work
```

The assert doesn't work because it's comparing a list of class instances (`assembly.components`) to a list of class types. Is there a good way to write this test?

Answer (score 4):

You could iterate through the list and use `isinstance()`:

```py
def count_instance(lst, cls):
    count = 0
    for i in lst:
        if isinstance(i, cls):
            count += 1
    return count
assert count_instance(assembly.components, Component) == 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert all of the elements in assembly.components into types with map() and then you can convert the map into a list and use the list.count function to see how many times the type appears in the list. Something like this:

```
assert list(map(type,assembly.components)).count(Component) == 3
```

if each item in assembly.components is already a type, you can just make sure its a list and then use the list.count function immedietly like this:

```
assert list(assembly.components).count(Component) == 3
```

Edit:
Also should you find yourself iterating over anything and want to compare the number of times a pattern appear, i believe its far better to use an int variable and increment it for each pattern you find rather than what you were doing which is creating entirely new lists and comparing them which in large quantities will slow down quite quick. (The increment method is how i bleieve the .count function works so where possible try to just use that.)

Answer (score 0):

```py
assert [type(comp) for comp in assembly.components] == [Component] * 3
```

This does the job - but I suspect there may be a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* assert the class types on each element in the list individually, however that's a relatively expensive operation, assuming you already know that each element in `components` will be a `Component` type.

Instead, you could just check the *length* of the list, as shown below; this assumes that you don't try to add an integer value, for example, to `components` outside of the class constructor. Though you could also assert that each element in the list is a `Component` type rather easily, using the builtin `map` operator and then unpacking the iterator result into a list, which is also shown as well.

> Note: attributes annotated as `ClassVar` are assumed to be class or static attributes only, and so will be ignored by the `dataclass` decorator when building a list of dataclass fields.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import ClassVar, List


@dataclass
class Component:
    name: str


@dataclass
class Assembly:
    names: ClassVar[List[str]] = ["Able", "Baker", "Charlie"]
    components: List[Component]

    def __init__(self):
        self.components = [Component(name) for name in self.names]


def main():
    """Assembly should be initialised with three Components"""
    assembly = Assembly()
    assert len(assembly.components) == 3  # works
    # bonus: check each element is a Component object also
    assert assembly.components == [*map(Component, assembly.names)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```